# How to develop offline map in android application?

Tags: android-studio-2.3

Hello Android developer i will develop offline map in Android using mapbox library and refer there example but in example give static LatLng. How can give dynamically LatLng? please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using google API you can get LatLng

Comment: have you done search option in offline map using Mapbox sdk. Do you have any idea about that ?.